# Connect Oracle Database from Test to Production Server

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

We are having 4 servers. In that one is Rackspace server and its a production server. There we are having Oracle database. The Port of that database is 2015, which is 
currently open for testing purpose.

I am trying to connect that database through SQL Developer from other 3 servers. From 2 servers i can able to connect.

Where as from 1 server (Server Name: TestServer) i cant able to connect.

In SQL Developer i am getting the error like this..

An error was encountered performing the requested operation: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Vendor code 20.

I have tried Ping from the 'TestServer' to 'ProductionServer'. It is working.

But whenever, i tried telnet it is showing 'Connecting To xxxxxx.com...Could not open connection to the ho
st, on port 2015: Connect failed'

I have also tried setting outbound rules in 'TestServer', but still i cant able to connect.

Since it is connecting for other 2 servers, i dont know where i am wrong.

Comment: Please check for firewall blocks.It may happen the particular IP is getting blocked so that you are unable to Telnet. Once firewall opening has been done you can go for telnet again.

Comment: Firewall is disabled in both the servers. But still not connecting.